# Side By Side Static Routes & Wild Card Routes In Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have a use case for a Laravel website I am working on to have some static routes sitting at the exact same level as the main wild card route.

EG:

Route: /store/cart        ***Static Route***
Route: /store/checkout    ***Static Route***
Route: /store/*           ***Dynamic Route***
Route: /store/*/*         ***Dynamic Route***
Route: /*                 ***Dynamic Route***

Been trying to figure out how to implement this routing structure in Laravel and while the static routing rules work fine as soon as I add the wild card routes I wind up with the wild card route trying to catch the static routes as well.

How would I be able to add routing rules to support this?

Answer (score 0):

change the conflicting routes to non conflicting.

```
Route: /store/cart Static Route => this is ok
Route: /store/checkout Static Route => this is ok
Route: /store/* Dynamic Route => /store/id/{id}
Route: /store// Dynamic Route => /store
Route: /* Dynamic Route => remove this and be specific by having more routes for the needs
```

Comment: But I need to have that final wildcard route as it displays general content pages from the database.

Comment: use /content_pages/*

Comment: routes must be non conflicting

Answer (score 0):

Us global constraint

```
Route::pattern('all','.*');
```

Then define your routes in order

```
Route::('store/cart', function () {});
Route::('store/checkout', function () {});
Route::('store', function () {});
Route::('store/{all}', function ($all) {});
Route::('{all}', function ($all) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working.

The first step was to use global constraint route patterns per @Aboalnaga...

```
Route::pattern('variableName','.*');
```

Each variable was defined with this route pattern to make it a wild card pattern.

The next step was to ensure route ordering. It appears as though when handling routing Laravel will work its way through the route list in order. As soon as it finds the first matching route it will stop there and run that route. So in order to handle a route chain in the form of `domain.com/store/cat-1/product`where the request could be for `domain.com`, `domain.com/store`, `domain.com/store/cat-1`, `domain.com/store/cat-1/product`, or `domain.com/some-content-page-from-database` the route needed to be defined as...

```
Route::get('/store/shopping-cart', 'onlineStore@showCart');
Route::get('/store/checkout', 'onlineStore@showCheckout');
Route::get('/store/checkout/payment', 'onlineStore@showPayment');
Route::get('/store/checkout/success', 'onlineStore@showPaymentSuccess');
Route::get('/store/checkout/error', 'onlineStore@showPaymentError');
Route::get('/store/{category}', 'onlineStore@showCategory');
Route::get('/store/{category}/{product}', 'onlineStore@showProductDetails');
Route::get('{article}', 'articles@showArticle');
```

By defining the routes in order and having the variable route defined as the last route at that level the variable route will only be triggered if the preceding routes don't match.